# Appengine owner invite gives Unauthorized errors

Tags: google-app-engine, authorization, owner

I did get an invitation to become the owner of a billed-enabled application from a regular google account (I have a google apps account).

I've tried both invite links and both gives the "You are not authorized to access this application." error that some others did get.

The funny thing is that previously I did get an invite to become a developer and it was working. But becoming the owner failed.
Is it due to the fact that I have a google apps account and the invite comes from a non google apps account?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually because when you click on the link you are already logged in using some other Google account that is not invited.  If you are using Chrome, try copying and pasting the link into an Incognito window.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, it did work using an incognito window, while completing exiting chrome did not work...I guess I was logged into multiple account although the proper account name was displayed at the top...

Comment: Exiting Chrome does not log you out -- logged-in status uses cookies which survive browser restart.  Multi-login is mysterious in many ways...

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this error from invitations I'm sending out to users who have opted out of being directly added to groups. I myself have a gmail account that I have used to opt out of being directly added, so I sent myself an invitation. The group was created with a domain apps account. After clicking on the "Accept" button / link in my email, the message I'm getting is along the lines "You are not authorized to access these contents. Please login using an authorized account", and there is a link for the login which brings to the domain apps login. If I then login with my domain apps account, the invitation is then completed and my gmail account is added to the group.
That worked for me as a test on myself, but the other users don't have the possibility of logging in with my administrative domain apps account, so how the heck do they accept the invitation?